# javascript object works on a html page but can not be loaded in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, object, declaration

this piece of code works fine on a html page. (header)

```
var startstop = new (function() {

    var $stopwatch, // Stopwatch element on the page
    incrementTime = 70, // Timer speed in milliseconds
    currentTime = 0, // Current time in hundredths of a second

    updateTimer = function() {
        $stopwatch.val(formatTime(currentTime));
        currentTime += incrementTime / 10;
    },

    init = function() {
        $stopwatch = $('.stopwatch');
        startstop.Timer = $.timer(updateTimer, incrementTime, true);
        startstop.Timer.stop();
    };

    this.resetStopwatch = function() {
        currentTime = 0;
        this.Timer.stop().once();
    };

    $(init);
});
```

When I try to access it on a Wordpress page where this javascript is loaded in the header using a theme function console shows  `$(init)` not a function.

What is wrong with this way of object declaration in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

This has really nothing to do with WordPress itself and probably has something to do with either your JavaScript code/functions not being loaded or the meaning of the variable `$`

Try the following:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
       // ALL YOUR CODE HERE
    });
}(window.jQuery));
```

This code wraps your code into a function that namespaces the `$` variable to jQuery and then executes that function immediately. By default, [WordPress uses `$.noConflict()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) which removes the `$` as a shortcut for jQuery.

The `$(document).ready` ensures that your code is not executed until the DOM is completely ready.

A shorter way to do this might be to just do this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // ALL YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

Comment: I was looking for such a solution. init() is called when I wrap the document ready, but then I get 

ReferenceError: startstop is not defined 

startstop.Timer.toggle();

which is defined in previous jquery loaded file:


;(function($) {


.... 

  this.toggle = function(reset) {
   if(this.isActive) {this.pause();}
   else if(reset) {this.play(true);}
   else {this.play();}
   return this;
  };
  
....   

})(jQuery);

Comment: Then you might need to bind `$(init)` to the `document.ready` event. See new answer.

Comment: SOLVED! I've added the document ready function and then I had to move the  startstop variable declaration outside the document ready function so its reachable globally. Thanks for your help Jorge Silva!

Answer (score 0):

Since `startstop` should be available globally and is set in the header, you should only call `$(init)` after the `document.ready` event has been triggered. This should be done inside your `starstop` function so that your `startstop` is available globally (that's bad practice, but you code will work).

Also change all your references form `$` to `jQuery`, just in case.

```
var startstop = new (function() {

    var $stopwatch, // Stopwatch element on the page
    incrementTime = 70, // Timer speed in milliseconds
    currentTime = 0, // Current time in hundredths of a second

    updateTimer = function() {
        $stopwatch.val(formatTime(currentTime));
        currentTime += incrementTime / 10;
    },

    init = function() {
        $stopwatch = jQuery('.stopwatch');
        startstop.Timer = jQuery.timer(updateTimer, incrementTime, true);
        startstop.Timer.stop();
    };

    this.resetStopwatch = function() {
        currentTime = 0;
        this.Timer.stop().once();
    };

    // Call this function when document.ready is triggered
    jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        $(init);
    });
});
```